# Use include(LocalInstallDirs) instead of include(GNUInstallDirs)?

Tags: c++, cmake, installation, header-files

We have a C++ library which provides a [`CMakeList.txt` file](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt), and it leads with the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.5 FATAL_ERROR)    
project(cryptopp)

set(cryptopp_VERSION_MAJOR 5)
set(cryptopp_VERSION_MINOR 6)
set(cryptopp_VERSION_PATCH 5)

include(GNUInstallDirs)
...
```

According to the CMake manual at [`GNUInstallDirs`](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/GNUInstallDirs.html):

> Provides install directory variables as defined for GNU software...
>
> ```
> ...
> INCLUDEDIR       - C header files (include)
> OLDINCLUDEDIR    - C header files for non-gcc (/usr/include)
> ...
> ```

Our policy is install into `/usr/local`; and don't install into `/usr`. Installing the library into `/usr` on some platforms breaks the library because the compiler treats all headers in `/usr/include` as C files, and ***not*** C++ header files. OpenBSD is one that breaks us, but it handles the library header files as expected when they are installed into `/usr/local/include`.

I perform *a lot* of cross-platform testing, and I don't know of any Unix compatible distributions that fail to support software installations into `/usr/local`. I know we are safe to install into `/usr/local` when its available.

I visited [CMake modules](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-modules.7.html?highlight=install), but I don't see a choice for something other than `GNUInstallDirs`. How do we specify something similar to `include(LocalInstallDirs)` instead of `include(GNUInstallDirs)`?

Comment: Module `GNUInstallDirs` provides conventions commonly used in GNU-compatible projects. If you don't like these conventions, write your module which setup directories as you need. Note, that module [GNUInstallDirs](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/GNUInstallDirs.cmake) provides **customizable definitions**: `If the includer does not define a value the above-shown default will be
used and the value will appear in the cache for editing by the user.` So you may include given module and modify some of directories it setups.

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance... Isn't Cmake supposed to do these things? Why do I have to do nearly everything by hand? What good is makefile generation without configuration?

Comment: `Isn't Cmake supposed to do these things` - **which** things? Decide for you where your deliverables should be installed? - No, it allows you to decide that. Provide a module per each *possible* installation convention? - No, there is no single or few conventions which covers almost everyone needs. `Our policy is install into /usr/local ...` - Why do not write module, which **express your policy**? I have written [one](https://github.com/euspectre/kedr/blob/master/sources/cmake/modules/path_prefixes.cmake) and use it for projects in which I participate.

Comment: @Tsyvarev - OK, I bite... How are we supposed to install modules on users system. We don't control a user's system. Cmake is expected to provide useful and common ones. We can't even get processor and machine information from Cmake for heaven's sake. If you are somehow trying to find safe harbor with "`/usr/local` is not standard", "determining the cpu is not common" or "determining the machine is not common",  then that's damn near laughable.

Comment: `How are we supposed to install modules on users system.` - If you mean `LocalInstallDirs.cmake` module, no needs to *install* it on user system. Just include it in every project (sources) you provide and use while building. `Cmake is expected to provide useful and common ones.` - CMake provides `GNUInstallDirs` module, which describes quite common conventions. BTW, conventions about installation directories are different even for distinct Linux distros, and there is no generic mechanism (except reading docs) to extract them for particular distro. CMake cannot handle that.

Comment: @Tsyvarev - the more I interact with you, the more I find your response s to be FanBoi banter. `GNUInstallDirs` is *not* nearly as common as you think. Additionally, it breaks C++ libraries. Every major Unix compatible I am aware supports `/usr/local`. The same cannot be said of `GNUInstallDirs`. So you are effectively arguing the most supported configuration in the Unix & Linux world is untenable; while the one that is less supported is viable. The arguments you are begging make no sense.

Comment: Hmm, default value for *CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX* on Unix-like systems is `/usr/local`. So if you use variable *CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR* for `install()` your headers, they will be installed into `/usr/local/include`, as you want. So, what is a problem? Just do not use *CMAKE_INSTALL_OLDINCLUDEDIR*, which, according to naming, refers to some old convention.

Comment: I think @jww did not realize that `GNUInstallDirs` are relative paths appended to `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`, with the exception of `OLDINCLUDEDIR` (which you don't have to use).