# CMake installs to bin/lib but app can't find lib

Tags: linux, cmake, installation

I'm building a multi-binary project with cmake and deploying in Debian.  CMakeLists.txt reduces down to something like this:

```
add_library(mylib SHARED lib.cpp)  #creates libmylib.so
add_executable(myapp main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myapp my-lib)

install(TARGETS mylib myapp
        RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
        LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
       )
```

If I install this to (`-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr`) then I have no problem. But if I install to somewhere else like (`-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/myapp`, or even `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local`), then I have a problem.

**When I run `$ /opt/myapp/bin/myapp` my application can't find the .so.**

I could deploy a script with myapp which sets:

```
#!/bin/sh
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
exec ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin/myapp $*
```

But this feels like a hack.  Plus, the script would need to be generated at configure time with `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib`.

I imagine that there's a more native way to handle this which lets me simply execute my application from `/opt` or `/usr/local` after installation.  It would preferably handle this at configure, compile, or install time instead of just before runtime and preferably wouldn't require someone to modify their `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`.

Could you please tell me if there is some way to deploy the standard `bin`,`lib` structure in linux to arbitrary paths without the need for pre-runtime scripting?

Comment: `bin/lib/` is a bit unusual. On Linux systems the convention is detailed in GNU Coding Standards at [7.2.5 Variables for Installation Directories](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Directory-Variables.html). Also see [Use include(LocalInstallDirs) instead of include(GNUInstallDirs)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39489560/608639)

Comment: I don't think it's that unusual.  The [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#OPTADDONAPPLICATIONSOFTWAREPACKAGES) serves as the base for for many unix-like distros including debian. It defines `/opt/<package>/[bin|lib]` as a very reasonable place to install software packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should:

- use rpath (Unix) or loader_path (MacOS)
- or install it in regular system path (/usr/lib or /usr/local/lib etc...)
- or use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Example to set RPATH:

```
if(APPLE)
  set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "@loader_path/../lib;@loader_path")
elseif(UNIX)
  set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "$ORIGIN/../lib:$ORIGIN/")
endif()
```

note: on macos you should now use @rpath
note2: on macos you can use `otool -l` and `otool -L` to introspec.
note3: you can use `ldd lib.so` and `objdump -p lib.so` on GNU/Linux.

Note: Prefer to use [GNUInstallDirs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GNUInstallDirs.html?highlight=gnuinstalldir)

```
include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
  INCLUDES DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)
```

Comment: Tried this on Arch Linux (still need to test on Debain).  I got it to work with the `"$ORIGIN/../lib:$ORIGIN/"` line.  The `if` condition may need to be changed to `if (UNIX AND APPLE)` removing the `NOT`.  I think it got a little backwards there.

Comment: I would love to use GNUInstallDirs but I need this package to be relocatable.